# How to narrow down methods with body parameters in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

It's pretty like [params](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) in @RequestMapping annotation, which narrows down the matching methods with query parameters. Instead, I want to achieve this with body parameters (like JSON-format). Do I need to implement a custom @RequestMapping annotation?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can achieve it using @RequestBody. It matches payload with names specified in code.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `@RequestBody`. Note that this not only allows *POJO*, you can use it with a *Map* too.

With a *POJO*:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String doSomething(@RequestBody MyDto dto) {
    return service.requestOTP(dto.getField1(), dto.getField2());
}
```

With a *Map*:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String doSomething(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {
    return service.requestOTP(body.get("field1").toString(), body.get("field2").toString());
}
```

**NOTE:** If you would like to validate properties of an object used with `@RequestBody`, you can add `@Valid` annotation. For instance, the following will cascade the validation on the model and the models sub model fields(if found).

```
public class MyDto {
    
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private String field1;
    
    private String field2;
    
    //getters and setters
}

@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String doSomething(**@Valid** @RequestBody MyDto dto) {
    return service.requestOTP(dto.getField1(), dto.getField2());
}
```

Check here for a brave introduction for `@Valid` https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/bean-validation/cascaded-validation.html